# Could not activate JNI Handle of java type MvxRecyclerView

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, mvvmcross, android-support-library

I'd like to implement MvxRecyclerView, but I get following exception during runtime in SetContentView():

```
System.NotSupportedException: Could not activate JNI Handle 0x32700041
(key_handle 0xb29d17e8) of Java type
'mvvmcross/droid/support/v7/recyclerview/MvxRecyclerView' as managed
type 'MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView'.
```

I use the latest NuGet packages of Xamarin.Android.Support.. (23.3.0) and MvvmCross (4.1.6 / 4.1.7).

Any idea what causes this exception?

Comment: I have the same error in my project.  It doesn't happen with the MvvmCross 4.1.4 and earlier.  The problem only happens after updating to 4.1.7 then loading a fragment with a MvxRecyclerView inside it.  The inflate call is failing. Downgrading back to 4.1.4 makes the error go away.

Comment: Leaving the Xamarin Android packages at 23.3.0?

Comment: Yes, I've been using 23.3 for a while.  The problem seems to be in MvvmCross.Droid.Support v4.1.7.  I have reverted back to 4.1.4 for now.  If this doesn't get any attention I may open an issue on Github to see if anyone can shed any light on this.

Comment: Please open an issue on GitHub :)

Comment: Can't downgrade to 4.1.4. MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging was unlisted and so the dependency check failed for Droid.Support to 4.1.4.

Comment: Also works with Droid.Support 4.1.5..

Comment: Any exception thrown in constructing the managed class (ctor and field initializations) can cause this, it appears. In my case it was a null exception. Completely obscured by this error. I don't know if support packages could really matter other than not burying the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More information now on the issue from Ken Kosmowski:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/issues/252

Use the workaround by @kjeremy referenced there, till the issue got fixed:
"The workaround consists of adding Resources\values\attrs.xml file to your Droid project with the following content:"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxRecyclerView">
    <attr name="MvxItemTemplateSelector" format="string" />
  </declare-styleable>  
</resources>
```

For completion purpose.

**With MVVMCross 4.2.0**

You should remove the attrs.xml and change all of your MvxItemTemplateSelector references to MvxTemplateSelector.